# Local Version of PhoneGap Build

Tags: cordova

One of the great things about PhoneGap Build is that I can upload my code and it automatically generates the necessary files to build for all devices. I am currently trying to build an application that I want to try out quickly, but would rather build locally than via PhoneGap build, but do not want to have to go through the tedium of setting up the relevant SDKs etc.

Are there any alternatives to Build available? I have no issue downloading a huge download, but I am looking for a neat deployment solution, either command line, or using maven or ant to generate the deployment packages? Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a minimum you will need all the SDKs for each of the platforms you plan to build and since you have to have a Mac to build iOS applications you will need to ensure you're on a mac, or if you're building Windows Phone or Blackberry apps you'll need to be on Windows.  I think the short answer is there's no way to do what PhoneGap build does on a single local system.

Comment: shame...I was hoping there may be a mac, linux and windows distro that contained the SDKs and build scripts that could build for the platforms it could support. I appreciate that all platforms are not possible from all OSs, but find the current method far too laborious.

Comment: @rooftop would you please guide me how to create build locally without uploading? Please tell me the exact steps or guide me through tutorial. Thanking in anticipation.